# CR_FAILURE in cfgmgr32.h

Tags: c++, winapi

I have two questions.
What exactly is `cfgmgr32.h` and what does `CR_FAILURE` indicates (other than just a failure)

as a reference I found [this file](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/mingw/include/ddk/cfgmgr32.h) where `CR_FAILURE` is defined as `0x13`

I am getting this value when trying to eject a USB programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This header is used by Device and Driver Installation Reference. For more information, refer to this document below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/cfgmgr32/

For CR_FAILURE, it seems when you attempt to eject a parent node that had multiple children, you will get this error. Ejecting the child rather than the parent may resolve the issue.

Best Regards,
Baron